# How to toggle multiple initial items in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

http://plnkr.co/edit/nEfBE33AJen3mz9YvjeC?p=preview

I have some data that populates a list, and I want the **first 3 items** in that list to gain the `selected` class.

I'm able to give the first item, or any single item that class with the following code, but my question is how would you toggle multiple items on first load?

[image]

```
  .controller('PageCtrl',
      ['$scope',
      function($scope) {

      var vs = $scope;
      vs.message = "1st, 2nd and 3rd item should be selected by default:";
      vs.toggleTags = { item: 0 }; // This gives the first item the selected class

      vs.myModel = [
        {name: 'aaa'},
        {name: 'bbb'},
        {name: 'ccc'},
        {name: 'ddd'},
        {name: 'eee'},
        {name: 'fff'},
        {name: 'ggg'}
      ];
  }]);
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="m in myModel" data-ng-class="{'selected':toggleTags.item == $index}">
        <div class="tag">{{m.name}}</div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between us, I am not a fan of keeping hidden state through very awkward ifs in the view. This is not a place for it. As such, here is a modification to allow you to select multiple items:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(k, m) in myModel" data-ng-class="{'selected':toggleTags.item.indexOf(k) > -1}">
        <div class="tag">{{m.name}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Your `toggleTags` then becomes:

```
vs.toggleTags = { item: [0, 1, 2] };
```

Cleaner, less surprising and easier!

Comment: Nice! Clean syntax :) and I see how this can be used to easily load up custom saved selected settings.

Answer (score 1):

I originally had this as a comment that I accidentally deleted, so I figured I'd go ahead and put it as an answer rather than re-comment, although Sébastien's answer has more flexibility.  This only works for the first *X* items, rather than being able to pick and choose:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="m in myModel" data-ng-class="{'selected':toggleTags.item >= $index}">
        <div class="tag">{{m.name}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```